# Flutter social media auth integration - Some of the permissions below have not been approved for use by Facebook

Tags: flutter, firebase, facebook

I am trying to get my Flutter app to have a "log in with Facebook" option where I get the email address and name of the user (nothing else).

I am using the [flutter_facebook_auth](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_facebook_auth) plugin with the default scopes.

Right now, login is working, and I get the display name, but **the email address is empty** and the users get this message when they try to log in:

[image: Facebook login problem]

I have done as it says and gone to the "App Review" section but there is no option for me to submit for review retrieving the email address.

I see this:

[image: Submit for review]

And then when I click "Request Permissions or Features", I get:

[image: Request features]

And then inside "Authentication and account creation", I get:

[image: Email requirement]

So I meet the requirements with a verified business and have answered the data protection questions about my use of the email address, what more can I do?

It doesn't seem to matter if I'm in developer or live mode.

I would say that the App I can connected to is not released yet (internal testing only right now) but I'd hope to be able to test this without that being a problem.

Comment: What scopes is your app requesting?

Comment: Just the defaults for the dart package flutter_facebook_auth, which are "email" and "public_profile" (same as are enabled above) @ceejayoz

Comment: It says there the user already logged into the app before - did they decline the email permission at that point perhaps? Users will not automatically get asked again for a declined permission.

Comment: In this case, that user was me and I didn't get asked if I wanted to share my email but I would have said yes if so...

Comment: @Kram may i know if u resolve this issue? i am getting same error as u